# API KIT Console in Mule not showing any Output

Tags: raml

I tried to look through all the tutorials for RAML and I was pretty excited.

I found most of the online resources available but I could not understand why, when i set up everything and the flows are generated, then i run it locally as a mule application, when i point to localhost:8081/api/console/ i get a huuuuuuuge json response, but not the UI described for example [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit+Tutorial).

Comment: I had a similar issue with the console coming back as xml because I explicitly set the contentType and mimeType to application/xml on the http-inbound-endpoint.  Don't do that otherwise the console and related css/js resources don't render correctly in the browser.  Omit contentType and mimeType on the http-inbound-endpoint and don't define any json transformers in the main apikit router flow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes i also faced the same issue with Any Point Studio. It is not at all displaying in the API KIT Console present in Any Point Studio. But to feel good and to see the output i have just tried it with Google Chrome Browser and i got the expected User Interface as i was expecting from API KIT Console. Hope this issue will be fixed from next release onwards.

Here is the URL i used to see it on Browser : `http://localhost:8081/remote-vending/api/console/`

Here is my output from Google Chrome browser for the [API KIT Tutorial](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit+Tutorial)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My GUI didn't show in the Anytime studio tab: APIkit Consoles, one way to fix this:

1. make sure you have started your application
2. right click for the context menu
3. select encoding
4. click auto-select

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and resolved it by removing invalid whitespace. One of the example files I was including had an invalid trailing space.

The way I found out;

- Open the Network panel in the Developer Toolbar in your browser
- Go to http://localhost:8081/api/console/
- Find the response for a request to '/api' with the request header 'Accept:application/raml+yaml'.

This response should contain the fully compiled RAML, where all include files have been included. 
Copy this entire content into a new RAML-file in Anypoint Platform API Designer or some other YAML editor with error reporting.
It highlighted the invalid whitespace immediately for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work Out of the box.
It could be a bug of an earlier version.

Could you check the behaviour in more recent releases?

Comment: In general I have no issue with the latest apikit, but with the specific [twitter example](http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/twitter/api/twitter-rest-api/twitter-rest-api.raml) i still get the same json response.
I do not know why this is happening, but will all my other RAML files it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my default browser from Firefox to Chrome resolved the issue for me.